# Messagebox is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using VS 2010 for develop a web application.After the 'Admin' give approval for a company, the messagebox have to display with the message that "Vendor ID:lblPage2ID modified as "Approved" (or "Not Approved" or "Pending") upon the radio button selected by the 'Admin'.How to do it ? Please refer the inline code below and tell me how to place the radio buttons in straight line.

```
   protected void rblTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
     _DAL.ExecuteSQL("UPDATE Company_Info SET 
          Approval_Status='"+rblTest.SelectedValue+"' WHERE Vendor_ID= '" +lblPage2ID.Text +"'");
          ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"callfunction",
        "alert('Approval Status modified in database');", true);
      //  Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock (typeof(Page),"SCRIPT",
         string.Format("alert(Approval Status modified as '" +rblTest.SelectedValue+"')"), true);
      //  HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert (Approval Status modified as 
         '" + rblTest.SelectedValue +"');</script>");
      //  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript (this.GetType ), "callfunction", 
            "alert('Approval Status modified as '"+rblTest.SelectedValue+"');",true);
    }

    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblTest" align = "center" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"   Width="152px" onselectedindexchanged="rblTest_SelectedIndexChanged" style="margin-left: 0px"> 
            <asp:ListItem  Text="Approved" Value="YES"></asp:ListItem> 
            <asp:ListItem  Text="Not Approved" Value="NO"></asp:ListItem> 
            <asp:ListItem  Text="Pending" Value="PEN"></asp:ListItem> 
     </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

[image: radiobutton]

Comment: Protip: concatenation of SQL parameters is not the way to go, it will leave you open to SQL injection attacks. Not relevant to your question, but you should know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set the RepeatDirection property of the RadioButtonList control to horizontal.

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblTest" align = "center" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true"   Width="152px" onselectedindexchanged="rblTest_SelectedIndexChanged" style="margin-left: 0px"> 
            <asp:ListItem  Text="Approved" Value="YES"></asp:ListItem> 
            <asp:ListItem  Text="Not Approved" Value="NO"></asp:ListItem> 
            <asp:ListItem  Text="Pending" Value="PEN"></asp:ListItem> 
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```